# Remove redundant spaces when render inside a <p> tag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to render a paragraph without redundant spaces. For example:

```
<p>There are cars, dogs, computers and houses!</p>
```

I have written the following code:

```
var objects = new List<string> { "cars", "dogs", "computers", "houses" };

<p>
    There are
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (objects.Count > 1 && i == objects.Count - 1)
        {
            @:and
        }
        else if (i > 0)
        {
            @:,
        }
        @objects[i]
    }
    !
<p>

@* This code will be rendered incorrectly by the browser like *@
<p>There are cars , dogs , computers and houses!</p>
```

How can I remove the spaces inside the `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the string outside or inside of the paragraph using a code block like so. Then, just throw it in your `<p></p>`

**Outside**

```
@{
    var objects = new List<string> { "cars", "dogs", "computers", "houses" };
    string myObjs = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (objects.Count > 1 && i == objects.Count - 1)
        {
            myObjs += " and";
        }
        else if (i > 0)
        {
            myObjs += ",";
        }

        myObjs += " " + objects[i];
    }
}

<p>There are @myObjs.Trim()!</p>
```

**Inside**

```
<p>There are 
@{
    var objects = new List<string> { "cars", "dogs", "computers", "houses" };
    string myObjs = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (objects.Count > 1 && i == objects.Count - 1)
        {
            myObjs += " and";
        }
        else if (i > 0)
        {
            myObjs += ",";
        }

        myObjs += " " + objects[i];
    }
}
@myObjs.Trim()!</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)` to join n-1 elements with ", " and then add last element with " and ".

```
<p>There are @string.Join(", ", objects.Take(objects.Count() - 1)) and @{objects.Last()}!</p>
```